# Django filter ModelMultipleChoiceFilter: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: django, django-filter

I have this code:

```
class MyFilter(FilterSet):
    transcribe_by = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        name='transcribe_by',
        label='Transcribed By'
    )
```

and I am getting this error when opening the page:

```
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `queryset` argument. `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` requires it. So add the queryset to your code:

```
transcribe_by = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True),
    name='transcribe_by',
    label='Transcribed By'
)
```

The error message is a bit unclear to be honest.